# change view elements size according to view size changing

Tags: swift

I have a view with 10 buttons , i want the buttons size to change when the view size changes .
or is there a way to set the buttons as children of the view so all the changes that apply at view will be applied to all the buttons

Comment: That's what auto layout is for, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

We can use autolayout to set the height for each of the 10 buttons to have a equal height with superView but with a multiplier of 1:10

Below is a sample screenshot showing the proportional height
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did it by embedding the buttons in Stack and multiplying the stack size with a percentage of screen size , first i get the screen size .

```
let screenSize : CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height
buttonsStack.frame = CGRect(x: screenWidth * 0.75 , y: screenHeight * 0.3 , width: screenWidth * 0.27 , height: screenHeight * 0.67)
```

X , Y are the position of the stack according to screen size .

Answer (score -2):

The only way I know to change the size of an element and keep it relative to the size of the parent container is to use the (%) size.

```
// index.html
<body>
   <div> 
      <a class="my-button" href="#">click me</a>
      <a class="my-button" href="#">click me</a>
      <a class="my-button" href="#">click me</a>
      <a class="my-button" href="#">click me</a>
      // .... more buttons
   </div>
</body>
```

then

```
// style.css

.my-button {
    width: 5%;
}
```

Comment: but i'm using swift